# Locale Specific Time Formatting

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm wondering if there are any time formats in Joomla? I see `JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC?')`.
Is there nothing comparable for times?

Comment: Could you expand a little on what you're trying to achieve? Do you have a date which you're trying to format into something else for example?

Comment: @Lodder I want to format a time using the settings for the selected locale (language/country).

Answer (score 1):

You can find different formats in **yoursite/language/en-GB/en-GB.ini**
something like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="y-m-d"
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you could use something like this:

```
$date = JFactory::getDate();    
echo $date->calendar('j F Y', false, true);
```

With the calendar method you can use the **[PHP date format characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** to format accordingly.

Other option:

```
JFactory::getDate()->format('%a %d %b %Y - %H:%M');
```

Read more:

- **[Joomla JDate documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_JDate)**
- **[Joomla JDate API](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDate.html)**